# Xamarin Forms with MvvmCross 5.7 First View not loaded

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin Application together with MvvmCross 5.7 and wanted to moved it completly to Xamarin Forms. It builds and starts as expected, but the first page isn't loaded.

[image]

I created the projects based this template: https://github.com/martijn00/MvxForms

Also I created a test project to see if something is wrong with my existing project: https://github.com/NPadrutt/XFTestProject

Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Either add a SplashScreen Activity who inherits from MvxSplashScreenActivity and with the method override:

```
    protected override void TriggerFirstNavigate()
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        base.TriggerFirstNavigate();
    }
```

Or add these lines to the OnCreate Method in the MainActivity:

```
        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();
        InitializeForms(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't neet to call `startup.Start()` in your MainActivity nor you need to init xamarin forms. It's done for you now (check `RunAppStart` method in [mvvmcross sources](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1601987a092370e7e9414abd1ef8f421f1c4af10/MvvmCross.Forms/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.cs) for `MvxFormsAppCompatActivity` class).

From a quick glimpse at your GitHub repo, it looks like you're not decorating your view (i.e. `WelcomView`) with `[MvxContentPagePresentation()]` attribute (e.g. [example from MvvmCross Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1601987a092370e7e9414abd1ef8f421f1c4af10/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.UI/Pages/RootPage.xaml.cs)). Add it in your `WelcomeView.xaml.cs` file and check if that helped

If it's a fresh project, you might want to consider using latest version of MvvmCross ([v6](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-6.0.0-release/)). There's an awesome [step by step guide to setup Xamarin.Forms with it by Nick Randolph](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2018/04/13/MVX=0F-A-first-MvvmCross-Application-(MVX1-days-of-MvvmCross).aspx)

Comment: I guess that is with MvvmCross 6.0 and not with 5.7? In the 5.7 release branch the startup.start() is mentioned as required when you do not have a splash screen. And the project is just a minimal test example for an existing project i want to migrate from embedded forms to complete xamarin forms. I had a look at MvvmCross 6.0 as well. But I use AutoFac  and the Extras Library is not updated for it as of now :)

Comment: @NPadrutt no, there's no need for you to call `Start` in the `MainActivity` for both 5.7 and 6.0 versions. The github sample by Martjin is out of date now, so don't use it as an example. If you want to have a look at how things could be done using MvvmCross, check out the [Playground projects in the official MvvmCross repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground)

Comment: mh, I see. thanks for the hint. Actually the startup.start() was from the 5.7 Release Playground: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/release/5.7.0/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Droid/MainActivity.cs

Comment: Hmm, you're right that there's that comment. However, you're using a SplashScreen in your project - so this doesn't apply. Anyways..I made a PR with a fix to your repo - I tested it, it works.